# Синонимизация меток о синтаксисе

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть такие метки:

- [синтаксис](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81) (226 вопросов)
- [syntax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) (96 вопросов)

Надо их синонимизировать.